# What if animals evolved from fungi?

Tags: fauna, flora, fungi

So in my book series, there is this planet called Axaca. However, it is very different from most of the galaxy in that its flora is almost completely fungal. Here are some things to know:

- Trees are replaced by giant toadstools
- Bushes are replaced by medium-sized fungus resembling coral
- The ground is full of mycelium
- The only plants are mosses that act as grass for this planet (and are eaten by herbivores and some fungi)
- This planet is home to some kind of sentient life (the dominant species is the anthropomorphic Chupacabra, but there are 2 others I need your help with coming up with)
- Animals (and thus sentient life) evolved from fungus and moss

Now for the question I need your help with: what would the biology of the wildlife (including the 2 other sentient species) be like if everything evolved from plants and fungi instead of heterotrophic bacteria?

Comment: This is wholly impossible, since fungi **eat food**, and thus require Something To Eat, which you don't have on a planet with so much fungus and so little Everything Else.

Comment: @RonJohn they eat the moss.

Comment: The real question here is how the [Chupacabra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chupacabra) got its name in a world with no goats to suck. Chupa[hongo](https://www.google.com/search?q=english+to+spanish+fungus&oq=engli&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i59j69i57j0l2.2464j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: @Giter I guess that makes sense.

Comment: I order to eat grass, you need to be mobile.  Fungi aren't mobile.

Comment: @RonJohn they could extend their mycelium out just under the ground to eat the moss.

Comment: @RonJohn please don’t unbuild the question’s premise if the OP hasn’t asked for it. There are many ways of getting around that particular problem, perhaps with algal symbionts (lichen) or simply by having an inexplicable sugary rain that is handwaved into the world.

Comment: Are any of the fungi on this planet capable of photosynthesis? Because even a plant completely covered in mosses (that get constantly eaten by everything else?) will not be able to produce a  lot of biomass without some other energy source.

Comment: @Dubukay worlds built around science (two of the tags are  #science-based and #evolution) require reasonableness, and this just isn't a reasonable question.

Comment: @RonJohn Disagree. Fungal-dominated ecosystems are a valid platform for worldbuilding, and it's up to the author to overcome that problem or ignore it. It's not our job to tell them whether or not such an ecosystem is impossible unless they ask for it - who knows what tricks they have up their sleeve to make it possible?

Comment: mosses evolved in modern plants why did this not happen on your planet? Mosses only survive in very humid climates.

Comment: @John because the giant fungi occupied most of those niches.

Comment: Weasel, I'd drop the sciency tags. The obvious direction to take is "who cares if it's possible --- it's fantasy / SF!" and move on from there. Edited accordingly.

Comment: giant fungi can't occupy those niches they are not producers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### In a very real way, we already did evolve from fungi

Consider the phylogenetic tree below. This is the evolutionary relationships among the Opisthokonta, the group of organisms that includes animals and fungi.

[image: A phylogenetic tree of Opisthokonta, from http://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/s2014/bender_bobb/classification.html]

Note that fungi serve as the outgroup for the Opisthokonta. This means that fungi and animals already share a common ancestor, and both lineages diverged from that ancestor.

Now, the term "evolve from" is a weird one. Usually, this phrase is intended to mean that an organism (such as fungi) is serving as the root (last common ancestor) of a phylogenetic tree including the specified organism. For example, if animals were a clade *within* the fungi, then it's much easier to argue that animals "evolved from" fungi, just as the hominids' position within the Great Apes lineage makes it easy to argue that humans "evolved from" monkeys. In your case, the anthropomorphic Chupacabra would instead belong to one of the fungal lineages below:

[image: Phylogenetic tree of fungi, from https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2014.00112/full]

However, the relationships described here are not so different from the ones described above. Assuming that the last common ancestor of fungi is still quite similar to the last common ancestor of the opisthokonts, then both ancestors are some form of [protozoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protozoa), which is what the [Metazoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metazoa&redirect=no) "evolved from" anyway. [This article](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/23/1/93/1193358) does a good job summarizing the emergence of fungi and animals from protistan ancestors.

Comment: I always knew I was part mushroom.  Everyone says I'm a fun guy.

Comment: Keep me in the dark, and feed me bullcrap...